# Safe truncate string contains color tag

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which contains color tags.

```
var myString = "My name is <color=#FF00EE>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#FFEE00>music</color>";
```

My string becomes "My name is ABCDE*(pink)* and I love music*(yellow)*"

I want to truncate if the string reaches max length but still keep color tag

```
var myTruncateString = "My name is <color=#FF00EE>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#FFEE00>mu</color>";
```

My string becomes "My name is ABCDE*(pink)* and I love mu*(yellow)*"

Do you have any suggestion?

```
var stringWithoutFormat = String.Copy(myString);
stringWithoutFormat = Regex.Replace(stringWithoutFormat, "<color.*?>|</color>", "");

var maxLength = 20;
if (stringWithoutFormat.Length > maxLength)
{
    // What should I do next?
}
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want? Do you just want to limit the number of characters? cause then:
    int max = 300;
    var myTruncateString = mystring[..max];

Comment: @Foitn I want to truncate my string but still keep color tags

Comment: Not so easy, effectively! I would first check the string length. If it's to long then search any `<color>` tag from the end. If one found then truncate its content or completely drop it if needed. If the string doesn't finish with a color tag then check its finishing position to see if we can truncate the text after it or if we also have to truncate its content.

Comment: You probably have to decode the XML structure, check total length of values in the decoded tags and truncate where needed (eventually removing whole tags or their children)... by the way, what you want to get if the whole "music" word is beyond the maximum length?

Comment: "I want to truncate if the string reaches max length but still keep color tag"
Max length counts also the <color> tags?

Comment: please share some code...

Comment: @Emanuele yes, I want to keep all color tags as original format

Comment: What OP is trying to achieve is similar to what is done (I think) when you put a link in a comment on SO: the length of the URL isn't counted in the characters limit of a comment. Here OP wants that whatever character is used in tagging is also not considered in the number of characters limit

Comment: @lolyoshi and instead of ABCDE which character are allowed?  Any? Brackets? Html tags?

Comment: @LaurentS. I put come of my code in the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a relatively simply and **NOT** error-handling example of what *I think* you're trying to accomplish:

- Don't count color tags when checking maximum length
- Remove characters from the end, don't destroy color tags
- If you end up with color tags with no text between them, remove those tags

Note: This code is not thoroughly tested. Feel free to use it for whatever you want, but I would write *a lot* of unit-tests here. In particular I'm scared about the existance of edge-cases that lead to an infinite loop.

```
public static string Shorten(string input, int requiredLength)
{
    var tokens = Tokenize(input).ToList();
    int current = tokens.Count - 1;
    
    // assumption: color tags doesn't contribute to *visible* length
    var totalLength = tokens.Where(t => t.Length == 1).Count();
    
    while (totalLength > requiredLength && current >= 0)
    {
        // infinite-loop detection
        if (lastCurrent == current && lastTotalLength == totalLength)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Infinite loop detected");
        lastCurrent = current;
        lastTotalLength = totalLength;

        if (tokens[current].Length > 1)
        {
            if (current == 0)
                return "";
            
            if (tokens[current].StartsWith("</") && tokens[current - 1].StartsWith("<c"))
            {
                // Remove a <color></color> pair with no text between
                tokens.RemoveAt(current);
                tokens.RemoveAt(current - 1);
                current -= 2;
                
                // Since color tags doesn't contribute to length, don't adjust totalLength
                continue;
            }
            
            // Remove one character from inside the color tags
            tokens.RemoveAt(current - 1);
            current--;
            totalLength--;
        }
        else
        {
            // Remove last character from string
            tokens.RemoveAt(current);
            current--;
            totalLength--;
        }
    }

    // If we're now at the right length, but the last two tokens are <color></color>, remove them
    if (tokens.Count >= 2 && tokens.Last().StartsWith("</") && tokens[tokens.Count - 2].StartsWith("<c"))
    {
        tokens.RemoveAt(tokens.Count - 1);
        tokens.RemoveAt(tokens.Count - 1);
    }
    return string.Join("", tokens);
}

public static IEnumerable<string> Tokenize(string input)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < input.Length)
    {
        if (input[index] == '<')
        {
            int endIndex = index;
            while (endIndex < input.Length && input[endIndex] != '>')
                endIndex++;
            if (endIndex < input.Length)
                endIndex++;
            yield return input.Substring(index, endIndex - index);
            index = endIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return input.Substring(index, 1);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Example code:

```
var myString = "My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#eeddff>music</color>";
for (int length = 1; length < 100; length++)
    Console.WriteLine($"{length}: {Shorten(myString, length)}");
```

Output:

```
1: M
2: My
3: My 
4: My n
5: My na
6: My nam
7: My name
8: My name 
9: My name i
10: My name is
11: My name is 
12: My name is <color=#ff00ee>A</color>
13: My name is <color=#ff00ee>AB</color>
14: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABC</color>
15: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCD</color>
16: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color>
17: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> 
18: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> a
19: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> an
20: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and
21: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and 
22: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I
23: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I 
24: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I l
25: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I lo
26: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I lov
27: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love
28: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love 
29: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#eeddff>m</color>
30: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#eeddff>mu</color>
31: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#eeddff>mus</color>
32: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#eeddff>musi</color>
33: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#eeddff>music</color>
34: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#eeddff>music</color>
35: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#eeddff>music</color>
36: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#eeddff>music</color>
37: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#eeddff>music</color>
38: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#eeddff>music</color>
39: My name is <color=#ff00ee>ABCDE</color> and I love <color=#eeddff>music</color>
... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

I generate 2 lists :

- One that contains the indexes of the real text
- One that contains the staring and ending indexes of tags

Then I take the text until the max length in the first array.
Finally, I check if there was an opening tag and if so, I close it.

N.B. : My code doesn't handle nested tags. You'd have to change the closing tag part.

```
public static string Truncate(string text, int maxLength)
    {
        if (text.Length <= maxLength) return text;

        var tagIndexes = new List<int>();
        var realTextIndexes = new List<int>();
        bool isInTag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] == '<')
            {
                isInTag = true;
                tagIndexes.Add(i);
            }

            if (!isInTag)
            {
                realTextIndexes.Add(i);
            }

            if (text[i] == '>')
            {
                isInTag = false;
                tagIndexes.Add(i);
            }
        }

        if (realTextIndexes.Count <= maxLength) return text;

        string truncatedText = text.Substring(0, realTextIndexes[maxLength - 1] + 1);

        // Should we close a tag ?
        for (int i = 0; i < tagIndexes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (tagIndexes[i] > realTextIndexes[maxLength - 1])
            {
                if ((i % 4) == 2) // If the next tag is a closing tag
                {
                    truncatedText += text.Substring(tagIndexes[i], tagIndexes[i + 1] - tagIndexes[i] + 1);
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        return truncatedText;
    }
```